# Present to the user limited library for state PHAuthorizationStatusLimited

Tags: ios, objective-c, phphotolibrary

Trying to use the following code when PhPhoto status is PHAuthorizationStatusLimited

```
PHAuthorizationStatus prevStatus = [PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus];
if (prevStatus == PHAuthorizationStatusLimited)
        {
            [PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorizationForAccessLevel:(PHAccessLevelReadWrite) handler:^(PHAuthorizationStatus status) {
                if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusLimited) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [PHPhotoLibrary presentLimitedLibraryPickerFromViewController:self];
                    });
                }
            }];
```

I get No known class method for selector 'presentLimitedLibraryPickerFromViewController: `[PHPhotoLibrary presentLimitedLibraryPickerFromViewController:self];`

I need to show the user the limited library to select photos. Are there any other options at this specific state? What am i missing?

Comment: Found it. You need to add Photos and import <PhotosUI/PhotosUI.h> frameworks in your project. Then call [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] presentLimitedLibraryPickerFromViewController:self];

Comment: Now i get Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PHPhotoLibrary presentLimitedLibraryPickerFromViewController:] any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to init viewController that handles the display before =>

```
UIViewController *presentedViewController = RCTPresentedViewController();
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] presentLimitedLibraryPickerFromViewController:presentedViewController];
```